# Bias Tee design for 150V AC and 150 DC at 40 - 50kHz

Tags: power-supply, ultrasound, biasing

my question seems to concern a really easy device. But since I am new to this field of the magical electrons I am very eager to be careful and thankful for any help.

My task is to power an [ultrasonic senscomp 600 transducer](http://www.senscomp.com/ultrasonic-sensors/ultrasonic-sensors.php#instrument-grade) with 150V DC and an added 150V AC at 40 and 50kHz. 
As stated on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee#Construction) I only have to dimension an inductor and a capacity, to fit following restriction:

\begin{align}
X_C &= \frac{1}{\omega C} = \frac{1}{2\pi f C} \ll Z_0,\\
X_L &= \omega L = 2 \pi f L \gg Z_0,\\
\end{align}

I have troubles with following questions:

1. As I understand, you can use a a bias tee to add an ac signal to a dc signal 
   but also use the circuit to subtract the AC from the DC+AC signal. Is this correct?
2. How do I choose a correct Z<sub>0</sub>? The [ultrasonic senscomp 600 transducer](http://www.senscomp.com/ultrasonic-sensors/ultrasonic-sensors.php#instrument-grade) does not list any impedance values of the transducer.
3. Is there any possibility to protect my sources and the driven transducer from wrong doing? I was thinking of diodes, to protect the costly sources.

It is hard to imagine, that i only need besides the BNC connectors two more parts to accomplish this.

Some friend suggested to connect the DC and AC source in series, but i don't feel good about this idea.

Thanks a lot - I hope this question fits your requirements.

Comment: How much current flows in each path?

Comment: @ThePhoton The [useless datasheet](http://www.senscomp.com/pdfs/series-600-instr-grade-ultrasonic-sensor-spec.pdf) suggests that the impedance is around \$\frac{1}{2\pi 1000 × 450 pF}\approx353 kΩ\$ @ 1 kHz. So if we naively extrapolate we get ~ 7 kΩ impedance at 50 kHz. So the current will be roughly 15 mA RMS.

Comment: @LuisvanBomel, I don't think you want a "Bias Tee", a Bias Tee (according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee)) splits up DC and AC to two different paths. You want to join those two paths together, so you should want a "Bias Tee **backwards** (with the schematic on the wiki in mind)". So on the wiki page, imagine your source coming from right and bottom and going left (backwards).

Comment: Don’t you think you should define the purpose? and some specs on the Tx pulse ? and the Rx design? I think you are over simplifying the  complexity of SONAR.  What substrate and acoustic port design is being used?

Comment: @HarrySvensson, it's normal to use a bias tee either way. What you're calling "backwards" is how it's normally used to bias a laser diode, but nobody ever bothers to specify that this is a "backwards" application. Using it the other way is common on the output of some RF amplifiers.

Comment: Those are sensors in the links and not transmitters. Can you clarify?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthanddirt the purpose is to send and receive by variating the distance and the angles of the Tx and Rx. The hole setup is considered as a training for me to get used to ultrasonics. The transducers will be used in air.

Comment: @Andyaka the transducers are suitable for both purposes -  sending and receiving, as stated in the [datasheet](http://www.senscomp.com/pdfs/series-600-instr-grade-ultrasonic-sensor-spec.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. The one time I needed a bias tee circuit is when I built PA0RDT's capacitative antenna. There is a full supply schematic on pages 14-15 here that should give a sense of how it is made: http://dl1dbc.net/SAQ/Mwhip/Article_pa0rdt-Mini-Whip_English.pdf
2. In the wiki page you linked there is a statement just above the formulas you quote: "Typically, the characteristic impedance Z0 will be 50 ohms or 75 ohms".
3. I don't really know what "wrong doing" you imply, but I'd definitely go for a fuse in the bias supply to protect the line and the power supply from short circuit surges. I used resettable fuses for convenience.

Comment: 2. I found two different definitions of "characteristic impedance" - One for the [connecting coax cable](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/antennas/coax/rf-coaxial-cable-impedance.php) which seems to be the correct one. An another source stated that you have to devide the voltage by the current. But as i don't know the flowing current or the impedance of the transducer the second option seems to be wrong.